# Every monic is a kernel

Tags: category-theory, modules, abelian-categories, morphism

This is part of Weibel's Exercise 1.2.2, where I have to show that in the category **R-Mod**, every monic is a kernel.

A *monic* morphism is defined to be a map $i \colon A \to B$ such that if $g \colon A \to A$ is such that $i \circ g = 0$, then $g = 0$, and a *kernel* of a homomorphism $f \colon B \to C$ is a map $i \colon A \to B$ such that $f \circ i = 0$ and $i$ is universal.

**Attempt**

Take a monic map $i \colon A \to B$ and $f \colon B \to 0$ be the zero homomorphism. Then obviously $f \circ i = 0$ and also if $i' \colon A \to B$ is such that $f \circ i' = 0$ there is a unique map $u \colon A' \to A$ defined to be the composition 
$$u \colon A' \to 0 \to A$$
It is unique since it is the composition of the zero map $A' \to 0$ and the zero map $0 \to A$.

It seems to be a problem with my attempt since I didn't use the fact that $i$ is monic, but I can't find any flaws in the argument, so I'd like if anyone could point them out and maybe a hint to complete the exercise. Thank you.

Comment: Typo in definition of kernel? (Should $i$ map $C \to A$?)

Comment: @hunter or in the definition of $f$ ($f \colon B \to C$). I'll edit it now.

Comment: Try $ f: B \to B/i(A)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $u: A'\to A$ is not unique such that the composition $A' \to A \to B$ is zero. Indeed, any map $A'\to A$ will have the property that the composition is zero.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it know. So the problem is that the $u$ I chose is not the one that works, or is it the $f$ I took? Thank you.

Comment: It's the $f$ that's wrong. The kernel of the zero homomorphism is the identity map $B \to B$.

Comment: So do you know what $f$ should I take to prove that part?

Comment: @user313212 yup, take $B \to B/A$ (where I mean quotienting by the image of $A$ of course).